# Are analytic $\mathbb{C}$-algebras henselian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A:=\mathbb{C}\{X_0, \dots, X_n\}$ be a convergent power series ring over $\mathbb{C}$ (equivalently, an analytic $\mathbb{C}$-algebra)  generated by $X_0, \dots, X_n$.

Is $A$ a henselian ring? If so, is the category of convergent power series ring over $\mathbb{C}$ equivalent to the category of local, henselian $\mathbb{C}$-algebras?

Comment: I added a tag that hopefully attracts more knowledgeable users. Let's see if it helps. May need 24 hours or more :-) Do you mean the ring of formal power series?  Or are you assuming convergence in some region??

Comment: I guess you will also need to add what you mean by 'the category of convergent power series over $\mathbb{C}$'? For example, what are the objects in this category?

Comment: The answer to the category question is "Of course not".